# Bootstrap toast remains on top (invisible)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

A **Bootstrap toast** is not closed (using the close button) before the app is "finished" (reloaded or at browser exit). When the app is started again the buttons under the "invisible toast" cannot be used although they are visible. So it looks like the toast "stays on top" but is invisible.

The solution to the problem is to click the button that shows the toast and close the toast. Now all buttons are clickable.

Bootstrap 4.3.1. Parcel is used. Can someone please explain?

Comment: To see a demo of this problem goto [tutorialrepublic](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=toast-methods) and adjust the window size so part of the buttons are under the toast. Press 'Show Toast', reload the page and if you hoover the cursor you can see where the toast was located (arrow instead of hand).

Comment: Seems to be a bug in Bootstrap. Issue [reported](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/28752)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your working demo, I was able to solve this by hiding the toast on page load in  both of the following ways (pick one)

1) Call jQuery `hide()` on page ready:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Hide the Toast
    $("#myToast").hide();

    $(".show-toast").click(function(){
        $("#myToast").toast('show');
    });
    $(".hide-toast").click(function(){
        $("#myToast").toast('hide');
    });
    $(".dispose-toast").click(function(){
        $("#myToast").toast('dispose');
    });
});
```

2) Add the `hide` class to the toast:

```
<div class="toast hide" id="myToast" data-autohide="false" style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0;">
```

Option 2 is cleaner.  But I understand that the `hide` class is deprecated in bootstrap, so use at your own [future] risk.  It does work in your version 4.3.1, though, so...

Comment: Solution 1 is not working in my app (it is rather complicated with cols and rows etc). Solution 2 is working. Thanks! But I think this is a bug in Bootstrap...

Answer (score 0):

@DBro - the 'hide' class works flawlessly. There is a new class for hiding elements new bootstrap (currently 4.4.1): "d-hide". Unfortunately the .toast() does not remove it so you have to do something like this:

```
var showNotification = function(){
    $('.toast').removeClass('d-none').toast({delay: 5000}).toast('show');
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.toast').addClass('d-none')},
    6000);
}
```

Waiting one second to add the class, just to let the fade transition to complete. Not perfect but gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

I found this works well.

```
        $("#myToast, #myToast2, #myToast3").on("show.bs.toast", function() {
            $(this).removeClass("d-none");
        })
        $("#myToast, #myToast2, #myToast3").on("hidden.bs.toast", function() {
            $(this).addClass("d-none");
        })
```